# Breeze not returning observables when .select() clause is used

Tags: breeze

This is the method that calls the controller for CustomerStrings entries:

```
  var getCustStrings = function (custStrings, custId) {

        var query = EntityQuery.from('CustomerStrings')
                .where('CustomerID', '==', custId)
                .select('CustomerStringNumber, CustomerString1')
                .orderBy('CustomerStringNumber');

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (custstrings){
                console.log(data.results);
                custstrings(data.results);
            }

            console.log('Retrieved [CustomerStrings] from remote data source');
        }
    };
```

The problem is that if I use .select(...) clause the returned objects are plain javascript objects, when I'm expecting them to be dependentobservables.

If I remove the .select() clause the returned result is right.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly how the select clause works.  If you would like to map the returned DTOs back to your entities just add a toType('') clause to your query

```
var query = entityQuery
    .from('CustomerStrings')
    .where(something)
    .select(whatever)
    .toType('CustomerStrings');
```